# r stop guessing names when root is similar

Tags: r

Is there an option in R that prevents it from returning values from field names with the same beginning if the one you asked for does not exist? This is causing me a fair amount of problems as my fields may or may not be present, and they have similar root names.

```
d <- data.frame(areallylongname = -99, y = 2, z = 0)

# How do I stop this returning a value
d$a 
#[1] -99

# it should return NULL like this
d$jjj 
# NULL
```

Comment: Although that is not what you are asking, `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)` would give you a warning when partial matching is done this way.

Comment: I usually check the pre-conditions in that case to ensure a stable interface I am programming against, e. g. `stopifnot(names(d) == c("areallylongname", "y", "z"))`. You could also include the data types (`class` or `typeof`) in the pre-condition-checks

Answer (score 4):

You can switch to bracket notation, which requires exact column names:

```
> d['a']
Error in `[.data.frame`(d, "a") : undefined columns selected

> d['y']
  y
1 2
```

Comment: thanks - yes that is one workaround. I was just wondering if there is an explicit Option X that exists to force my example to have  exact names because it seems quite a dangerous default to have.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid partial matching and return an error, the following could work.
However, this will make all other warnings to errors as well.

```
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE, warn = 2)

# test
d$a
```

> Error in `$.data.frame`(d, a) : 
>     (converted from warning) Partial match of 'a' to 'areallylongname' in data frame